# Query to get result from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I need is the stored procedure and according to 3 tables give me the below result:

What I have is :

Table 1: TBL_USER

```
userid   Client_name
------   --------
2101     client 1
2102     client 2
2105     client 3
2106     client 4
```

Table2: Accountbalance

```
Acbc_UserID    Acbc_Remained
-----------    -------------
2101           2.32
2102           2.727
2105           223.783
2106           26.77
```

Table 3 = opper_price

```
Opprice_UserID  Opprice_Price
-------         -------
2101            0.008
2101            0.008
2101            0.008
2101            0.008
2102            0.009
2102            0.009
2102            0.009
2102            0.009
2105            0.009
2105            0.009
2105            0.009
2105            0.009
2106            0.010
2106            0.010
2106            0.010
2106            0.010
```

(here we need an average for example `user_id 2106` has 4 price so we need to get the average which is again 0.009)

According to the table above i would like to get a below result:

if the user id does not exist in table 3 to use the average price of 0.006

```
Client_Name   average_price    Acbc_Remained     SMS_remain
Client 1      0.008            2.32             ( Acbc_Remained /average_price)
Client 2      0.009            2.727             (2.727/0.009=303)
Client 3      0.009            223.783           24864.7778
Client 4      0.010            26.77             2677

                                                 ========
                                                 Total of column SMS_remain
```

So what I want to do is to have this stored procedure and add it into the SQL Server email so the whole result table will be send as well.

This is what i have done till now but the price is NULL:

```
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT Prj_Users.Users_ID
        ,Prj_Users.Users_Name   AS prj_users
        ,Prj_AccountBalance.Acbc_Remained   AS Prj_AccountBalance
        ,Prj_OpperPrice.Opprice_Price   AS Price

  FROM Prj_Users LEFT JOIN Prj_AccountBalance
  ON Prj_Users.Users_ID = Prj_AccountBalance.Acbc_UserID
  LEFT JOIN Prj_OpperPrice
  ON Prj_OpperPrice.Opprice_UserID = Prj_OpperPrice.Opprice_Price

END
```

Thank you

Comment: So that it doesn't sound like you're simply outsourcing some work on SO, it may be best if you also post the queries you have tried so far, and where you need help with them.

Comment: What is your current query and what error are you getting?   Saying what you need isn't a question, so right now it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: the thing is i know how to do the join but i dont know how to create the columns that they dont exist like sms_remain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Client_Name
      ,average_price = avg(Opprice_Price)
      ,Acbc_Remaind  = avg(Acbc_Remained)
      ,SMS_Remain    = case when avg(Opprice_Price)=0 then 0 else avg(Acbc_Remained)/avg(Opprice_Price) end
 From TBL_User A 
 Join opper_price B on (A.userid=B.Opprice_UserID)
 Join Accountbalance C on (A.userid=C.Acbc_UserID)
 Group By Client_Name
```

Returns

```
Client_Name average_price   Acbc_Remaind    SMS_Remain
client 1    0.008           2.32            290.00
client 2    0.009           2.727           303.00
client 3    0.009           223.783         24864.7777
client 4    0.01            26.77           2677.00
```

This one includes the Total and is reduces the redundant calculations:

```
Select A.*
      ,SMS_Remain    = case when average_price=0 then 0 else Acbc_Remaind/average_price end
      ,Total_SMS_Remain =SUM(case when average_price=0 then 0 else Acbc_Remaind/average_price end) OVER () 
 From (
          Select Client_Name
                ,average_price = isnull(avg(Opprice_Price),.006)
                ,Acbc_Remaind  = isnull(avg(Acbc_Remained),0)
            From @TBL_User A 
            Left Join @opper_price B on (A.userid=B.Opprice_UserID)
            Left Join @Accountbalance C on (A.userid=C.Acbc_UserID)
            Group By Client_Name

      ) A
```

Returns

```
Client_Name average_price   Acbc_Remaind    SMS_Remain  Total_SMS_Remain
client 1    0.008           2.32            290.00      28134.7777
client 2    0.009           2.727           303.00      28134.7777
client 3    0.009           223.783         24864.7777  28134.7777
client 4    0.01            26.77           2677.00     28134.7777
client 5    0.006           0.00            0.00        28134.7777
```

Note on Client 5 the .0006 amd the 0 on Acbc_Remaind   this is done by using the ISNULL() function

Comment: I should add, depending on your actual data, you may want or need a left join and/or use isnull(value,0)

Comment: Hi thank you for your help.
Im getting below error:
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
Must declare the table variable "@TBL_User".

Comment: Remove the @ symbols.   I just created three @table variables rather than  creating an actual table

Comment: I updated the query removing the @ symbols

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Last thing is can you tell me if the avg(Opprice_Price) does not exist then i want to use the price 0.006. Can you tell me how i can do that?

Comment: Change Join to Left Join.   the calculated columns would show as NULL

Comment: john one last question how can i sum the  SMS_Remain column?

Comment: Sorry, I was pulled away.  What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a second query which has a total column.  Remember to take out the @

Comment: I updated the second query ... see note at the bottom

Comment: IMHO, having the .0006 hard-coded is dangerous.  I suspect this will change over time.   You may want to drop such items into  collections table with an effective date.

Comment: I goofed.   I had .0006 vs .006.  The second query has been updates

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. its working perfect..